# How do I use this iframe workaround for videos to work with ebay mobile app?

Tags: html, iframe, mobile, ebay-design-templates

I'm learning CSS at present in an attempt to improve my ebay templates and listings for mobile users. Long time Stack Overflow lurker, where until now I have always found other user posts resolves my problem, but this one has me stumbled.

I've trying to get You Tube videos that are embedded to my eBay listings to work via eBay mobile app.

To do so, I need to use iframes, however eBay doesn't allow iframes, but there are workarounds such as this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ax="ifr";var bx="ame src='htt";var cx="p://"
document.write("&lt;"+ax+bx+cx+"amarantha.pegasusweb.co.uk/swarovski-elements-crystal-iphone-4-4s/");
document.write("'width='100%' height='1500px' scrolling='no'>"+"</ifr"+"ame>");
-->;
</script>
```

I've not used JavaScript before, so I'm not sure if I am implementing it correctly. When I try to include it, instead of the iframe content appearing, the reassembled iframe code appears instead like this....

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hHkKn

Any ideas where I am going wrong please, or another way I can use iframe suitable for video use in eBay?

Answer (score 1):

I have spotted one mistake with your Javascript. There is no need to escape the < character with &lt; By doing this you are not injecting any html via document.write, but instead just adding plain text. I've updated the script below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ax="ifr";var bx="ame src='htt";var cx="p://"
document.write("<"+ax+bx+cx+"amarantha.pegasusweb.co.uk/swarovski-elements-crystal-iphone-4-4s/");
document.write("' width='100%' height='1500px' scrolling='no'>"+"</ifr"+"ame>");
-->;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply, however I have been using the object method but this is causing videos to not play via the ebay app, therefore need to use iframe so video will play as HTML5.

Comment: Just to add, I have actually been using this method for many years without fault. I'm now in the process of making my listing mobile friendly and that's when I discovered videos do not appear on mobiles using the ebay app. If I can use iframe, the video will at least then have a chance to play as HTML5 and hopefully should then work. The code above does work, at least for Stu (blogger) who coded it as I've seen his ebay listings, but I simply cannot get it to work due to the issues described above.

Answer (score 0):

Above code works for me.

Code must be inserted in HTML mode in ebay listing edit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ax="ifr";var bx="ame src='/";var cx="/"
document.write("<"+ax+bx+cx+"www.youtube.com/embed/nxiYmFRmTlE?showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;theme=light");
document.write("' width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen>"+"</ifr"+"ame>");
-->;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Eduscho. Sorry for late reply, hadn't seen this until now. I gave up trying to get this working, but if I come back to it, I will try your script, thank you.